connecting html form to my wix site database
I am trying build a customized form on wix using HTML. on submission i want the form data to store in my wix database i tried this simple code but is not working
i getting this error : TypeError: $w(...).onSubmit is not a function
HTML code.
    <form id="myForm">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

JS Code
 import wixData from 'wix-data';

    $w.onReady(function () {
      $w("#myForm").onSubmit((event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        let formData = {
          "name": $w("#name").value,
          "email": $w("#email").value
        };
    
        wixData.insert("FormSubmissions", formData)
          .then((result) => {
            console.log("Data submitted successfully", result);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error submitting form data", err);
         });
      });
    });



Where did you find onSubmit? In the documentation, I can only find onWixFormSubmit

You cannot simply add HTML to a Wix page like that.
The easiest thing to do is to use the built-in input elements in Wix to create the form. If you do that, you can even have it submit the data to the database without writing any code.
If you really need to write the HTML yourself, you'll need to use an iframe element or custom element. Then you have to write code to send the data from that element back to the page and then insert it into the database. It's a bit of a pain to do and should only be necessary if you're doing something with very specific and unusual requirements.
